# re-import a Python Module from a different location

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, reload, sys.path

I would like to import a module from one location, unload it, and then import a module of the same name from another location in python. Something like:

```
sys.path.append(module_location_1)
import module
unload module
....
sys.path.append(module_location_2)
import module
```

I tried the following approach below but have had no luck:

```
sys.path.insert(0, /path1)
import my_module
print my_module # <module 'my_module' from '/path1/__init__.pyc'>

sys.path.insert(0, /path2)
import my_module
print my_module # still gives: <module 'my_module' from '/path1/__init__.pyc'
```

Unfortunately after the second input I see the the module is still be loaded from the original location I added to my path. I have tried: 
1

- removing the first location from sys.path all together between imports
- imp.reload(my_module).
- both appending and prepending to the path

Thanks!